# Which IIS settings i have to use for using own password validation with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I've created a simple WCF Service which is hosted in IIS. Now i want to use my own userName authentication. 
My web.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfIIsBasicAuthTest.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior">
        <endpoint address=""
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            contract="WcfIIsBasicAuthTest.IService1"
            bindingConfiguration="MyBinding"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyBehavior">
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WcfIIsBasicAuthTest.MyValidator, WcfIIsBasicAuthTest"/>
            </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The Validator

```
namespace WcfIIsBasicAuthTest
{
    public class MyValidator :UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            if(!(userName == "test" && password == "test"))
            {
                throw new SecurityTokenException("Validation Failed!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If i start this WCF Service from within visual studio, i get the following error: `The authentication schemes configured on the host ('Ntlm, Anonymous') do not allow those configured on the binding 'BasicHttpBinding' ('Basic').`

If i try to connect to the service if it is hosted in IIS, i get error messages depending on which authentication type is set, but it doesn't work at all.

Error if only Anonymous authentication is enabled: `The authentication schemes configured on the host ('Anonymous') do not allow those configured on the binding 'BasicHttpBinding' ('Basic').`

If i set Basic Authentication in IIS, it demands a valid local user which i don't want to provide(since i want to write my own userprovider).

Any hints/links how to setup such a basic auth userprovider with wcf and iis?

Answer (score 2):

Can you set the below configuration for using your own UserNameValidator:

```
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
</security>
```

For that to work with basicHttpBinding you would need to have HTTPS setup as WCF doesnt allow username password being passed over the channel in clear text. The other alternative is to use wsHttpBinding.

Comment: Even with the website configured using https, i'm unable to use my own userprovider. Besides this, 'clientCredentialTyp="UserName"' is always invalid(or did i miss anything?)

Comment: Thats strange that "clientCredentialType=UserName" is invalid. Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: It just says: 'The clientCredentialType is invalid'
I can select from "None,Basic,Digest,Ntml,Windows,Certificate"

Comment: Its not for the transport element its for the Message element within the security element.